# retrieve data set having only a ChartPanel reference (Java + JFreeChart)

Tags: java, dataset, jfreechart

This question in partially related to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164340/modify-dataset-of-an-already-built-chart-with-java-and-jfreechart) on this subject.

I would like to know after a ChartPanel has been constructed :

```
public ChartPanel buildChart(){
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
...
    FreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("line chart example",
                "X", "Y", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    return chartPanel;
}
```

Can I retrieve the dataset used for generating chart, but having only a reference to chartPanel?

```
ChartPanel panel = buildChart();
panel.getDataset; //I'm looking for a way to retrieve the dataset, or XYSeriesCollection..
```

Is that possible? Can someone put me in the right direction?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a `dataset` reference available to the view, as shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo). Alternatively, you can drill down from the [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html), as suggested below.

```
ChartPanel chartPanel;
JFreeChart chart = chartPanel.getChart();
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYDataset data = plot.getDataset();
```

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522575/how-can-i-update-a-jfreecharts-appearance-after-its-been-made-visible).